# I am searching for the Eigen stuff of a non linear transformation

Tags: equation-solving, performance-tuning, probability-or-statistics, linear-algebra, vector

I have a slightly odd problem I have been working on as part of a project on probability models. The full problem itself is not relevant but here is where I am stuck.

I have a 6D space $P$, where all values are reals between 0 and 1 representing probibilitys. I also have two non-linear transformations from this space to $\mathbb{R}^3$ called $D:P \to \mathbb{R}^3$ and $ND: P \to \mathbb{R}^3$. I am interested in transformations $T_p: \mathbb{R}^3 \to \mathbb{R}^3$ where for all $p \in P$ it is the case that $T_p(ND(p)) = D(p)$. More specifically I want to find the Eigen stuff of $T_p$ in terms of the value of $p$.

That was a bit of an abstract overview so let's get into my code.

First I define a vector to represent the $ND$ transformation. Note that the vector $p$ is implicitly assumed to be {a,b,c,d,r,h}.

```
ndconVec = {(r*a^2 + (1 - r)*c^2)/(h*r*a^2 + 
     h*(1 - r)*c^2 + (1 - h)*r*b^2 + (1 - h)*(1 - r)*d^2) , (r*
      a*(1 - a) + (1 - r)*c*(1 - c))/(h*r*a*(1 - a) + 
     h*(1 - r)*c*(1 - c) + (1 - h)*r*b*(1 - b) + (1 - h)*(1 - r)*
      d*(1 - d)), (r*(1 - a)^2 + (1 - r)*(1 - c)^2)/(h*r*(1 - a)^2 + 
     h*(1 - r)*(1 - c)^2 + (1 - h)*
      r*(1 - b)^2 + (1 - h)*(1 - r)*(1 - d)^2)}
```

Next, I do the same thing for $D$

```
dconVec = {(r*a + (1 - r)*
       c)^2/(h*(r*a + (1 - r)*c)^2 + (1 - 
        h)*(r*b + (1 - r)*d)^2), ((r*a + (1 - r)*
        c)*(r*(1 - a) + (1 - r)*(1 - 
          c)))/(h*((r*a + (1 - r)*
           c)*(r*(1 - a) + (1 - r)*(1 - c))) + (1 - 
        h)*((r*b + (1 - r)*d)*(r*(1 - b) + (1 - r)*(1 - d)))), (r*(1 -
          a) + (1 - r)*(1 - 
         c))^2/(h*(r*(1 - a) + (1 - r)*(1 - c))^2 + (1 - 
        h)*(r*(1 - b) + (1 - r)*(1 - d))^2)}
```

Here I explicitly write down my assumptions. I do not know if this is the best way to do this but I think it at least works. Also, I introduce l which is going to be the Eigenvalue

```
$Assumptions = {Element[a | b | c | d | r | h, PositiveReals] && 
  a < 1 && b < 1 && c < 1 && d < 1 && r < 1 && h < 1 && 
   Element[l, Reals]}
```

Finally, I try to solve the problem.

```
Solve[ndconVec == dconVec l, {a, b, c, d, r, h, l}]
```

My Issue is that Solve never finishes running. This may be because it is too hard a computation but I am not sure. I would love if anyone could spot a bug in this code or even a way of working on this that would speed up the computation.

Thanks so much if you read all this, I know it is a lot.

Comment: "l" does nowhere appear in your equations. Further, your solution will be a 3 dimensional region.  One trivial  solution is: {a -> 1/2, b -> 1/2, c -> 1/2, d -> 1/2, r -> 1/2, h -> 1/2}

Comment: Yes, I found that one with find instance. I could not find an instance if I add ndconVec != {0,0,0}. That letter is a lowe case L, not an I.